# How to extract only particular key values from dict output?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

How can I extract all the 'ImageId' values from the below expected output which is in dict structure?

I tried to extract all values and convert them into json and tried to extract, but that doesn't seem to be working for me or may be not a good way of doing this task.

This code is from Boto3 documentation from [here](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_spot_fleet_requests).

Expected Output:

```
{
    'SpotFleetRequestConfigs': [
        {
            'SpotFleetRequestConfig': {
                'IamFleetRole': 'arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/my-spot-fleet-role',
                'LaunchSpecifications': [
                    {
                        'EbsOptimized': False,
                        'ImageId': 'ami-1a2b3c4d',
                        'InstanceType': 'cc2.8xlarge',
                        'NetworkInterfaces': [
                            {
                                'AssociatePublicIpAddress': True,
                                'DeleteOnTermination': False,
                                'DeviceIndex': 0,
                                'SecondaryPrivateIpAddressCount': 0,
                                'SubnetId': 'subnet-a61dafcf',
                            },
                        ],
                    },
                    {
                        'EbsOptimized': False,
                        'ImageId': 'ami-1a2b3c4d',
                        'InstanceType': 'r3.8xlarge',
                        'NetworkInterfaces': [
                            {
                                'AssociatePublicIpAddress': True,
                                'DeleteOnTermination': False,
                                'DeviceIndex': 0,
                                'SecondaryPrivateIpAddressCount': 0,
                                'SubnetId': 'subnet-a61dafcf',
                            },
                        ],
                    },
                ],
                'SpotPrice': '0.05',
                'TargetCapacity': 20,
            },
            'SpotFleetRequestId': 'sfr-73fbd2ce-aa30-494c-8788-1cee4EXAMPLE',
            'SpotFleetRequestState': 'active',
        },
    ],
    'ResponseMetadata': {
        '...': '...',
    },
}
```

Comment: [Minimal, complete sample code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) should be included in the [question itself](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/90527). Please read the help center documentation on asking, especially on [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
res = [i['ImageId'] for i in \
       d['SpotFleetRequestConfigs'][0]['SpotFleetRequestConfig']['LaunchSpecifications']]

print(res)

['ami-1a2b3c4d', 'ami-1a2b3c4d']
```

There are only 2 operations that are used:

1. Access a key of a dictionary via `d[key]`.
2. Access the element *i* of a list via `lst[i]`.

The most difficult part is identifying where you have lists and dictionaries. I recommend you look at each part of your input one step at a time: dictionaries are identified via `{}`, while lists `[]`.

**Setup**

```
d = {
    'SpotFleetRequestConfigs': [
        {
            'SpotFleetRequestConfig': {
                'IamFleetRole': 'arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/my-spot-fleet-role',
                'LaunchSpecifications': [
                    {
                        'EbsOptimized': False,
                        'ImageId': 'ami-1a2b3c4d',
                        'InstanceType': 'cc2.8xlarge',
                        'NetworkInterfaces': [
                            {
                                'AssociatePublicIpAddress': True,
                                'DeleteOnTermination': False,
                                'DeviceIndex': 0,
                                'SecondaryPrivateIpAddressCount': 0,
                                'SubnetId': 'subnet-a61dafcf',
                            },
                        ],
                    },
                    {
                        'EbsOptimized': False,
                        'ImageId': 'ami-1a2b3c4d',
                        'InstanceType': 'r3.8xlarge',
                        'NetworkInterfaces': [
                            {
                                'AssociatePublicIpAddress': True,
                                'DeleteOnTermination': False,
                                'DeviceIndex': 0,
                                'SecondaryPrivateIpAddressCount': 0,
                                'SubnetId': 'subnet-a61dafcf',
                            },
                        ],
                    },
                ],
                'SpotPrice': '0.05',
                'TargetCapacity': 20,
            },
            'SpotFleetRequestId': 'sfr-73fbd2ce-aa30-494c-8788-1cee4EXAMPLE',
            'SpotFleetRequestState': 'active',
        },
    ],
    'ResponseMetadata': {
        '...': '...',
    },
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I posted the wrong dict data, so I updated it above. Anyways, I tried your code res = [i['InstanceId'] for i in response['ActiveInstances'][0]['InstanceId']]
print(res) and got the error -string indices must be integers

Comment: I rolled your question back to its original state. If your question has changed, you should post a new question. I also updated my answer with the setup I used to demonstrate it is in line with your original question.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to use your code and I was able to extract the targeted values from the dict data structure by doing something like this res = [i['InstanceId'] for i in response['ActiveInstances']]